# Procoagulant salve/cream/gel?

Tags: wound, wound-care, topical-cream-gel, blood-clotting

Are there any salves or creams you can apply to a bleeding wound to rapidly end  bleeding by promoting clotting? And would it perform better than bandages?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "wound" you could consider a styptic pencil. It's generally used for nicks and small cuts, such as you get while shaving. Most drugstores sell them or you can order from Amazon. They are briefly mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihemorrhagic) on agents that stop bleeding. The article mentions several other products that are probably only available to doctors, and has a fair number of external links you could use to learn more about those products.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be useful, but cyanoacrylate-based glues have been used in surgical wounds for quite some time as an alternative to other methods. They won't work for all kinds of wounds and they have some downsides to know about.

Related bibliography: http://www.uptodate.com/contents/minor-wound-repair-with-tissue-adhesives-cyanoacrylates